# Django, Save email instead of username, table doesnt exist

Tags: django

So i'm trying to set up a form so that it saves the email instead of the username.

When i click signup, it says table (app_name.pages_user) Doesn't exist?

What am i doing wrong exactly? Is it because i need to have a table to have hte users save into? i thought this would just be saving to the auth_users table?

Heres my code

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=13)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return ""
```

**Views.py**

```
from pages.forms import SignUpForm

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

**only migration**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11 on 2018-03-21 13:52
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import django.contrib.auth.models
import django.contrib.auth.validators
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0008_alter_user_username_max_length'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('username', models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, unique=True, validators=[django.contrib.auth.validators.ASCIIUsernameValidator()], verbose_name='username')),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.', verbose_name='staff status')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.', verbose_name='active')),
                ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(max_length=150)),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(max_length=150)),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=254)),
                ('mobile_number', models.IntegerField(max_length=13)),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
                'verbose_name': 'user',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'users',
            },
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

**Edit**

Added extra code for the migration file

Comment: why don't you show your settings  (auth user model) and migration files?

Comment: AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'pages.User'

Comment: And i'll add the migration now :)

Comment: and you didn't forget to run ./manage.py migrate, right?

Comment: @EduardGamonal i most definitely didn't :)

Comment: your migration made me think that you changed to a custom user model  after using the regular one. docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project  say you should first set the auth user model in the settings, then make the migrations, and that it should be the first migration. kind of blind here, but it might be worth a try